# Tunning the output rate of spout in apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

How to limit the spout transferring tuple in second without using Sleep command in apache storm? for example, I don't want to use this code. Thanks

```
puplic Void Next Tuple(){
     utils.sleep(time);
}
```

Comment: If you enable fault-tolerance, you can limit the number of message in-flight by setting parameter "max.spout.pending". Furthermore, since Storm 1.0 there is back-pressure mechanism that can also throttle your spouts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want tuples to be emitted at a slower rate? As a programmer, this is a very simple solution you should already have figured out. The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
class MyClass {
private boolean timeUp = false;
public void nextTuple() {
    if (timeUp) {
      EmitMyTuple();
      ResetTimeCounterToZero();
      timeUp = false;
    } else {
      boolean greater = CheckIfTimeIsGreaterThanOneSecond();
      if (greater) {timeUp = true;}
    }
  }
  SleepForFewMilliseconds();
}
```